# Click the fancybox close button,and then href to another page

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have one question.
**After click** the fancybox close button,I want to href to another page(index.php).
If there any way can do it? Please help me.Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#various1").fancybox({
          'padding'         : 0,
          'overlayColor'    : '#000', 
          'overlayOpacity'  : 0.6, 
          'titlePosition'   : 'none',


      }).click(function(){
    $.fancybox.close();
    //window.location = "http://index.php";
    return false;  
    });
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Does your outcommented //window.location work?

Comment: ooh~ window.location="index.php"; This would run automatically.so I want to run this after close the fancybox "X" button

Comment: What you have written should work after uncommenting the commented code. Is there any error that you are getting? also if you are redirected to a different page the fancybox should close anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `afterClose` callback. Just add `afterClose`

```
        $("#various1").fancybox({
          'padding'         : 0,
          'overlayColor'    : '#000', 
          'overlayOpacity'  : 0.6, 
          'titlePosition'   : 'none',
           'afterClose'  : function() {
               location.href = "index.php";
            }
        });
```

**Edit :**

```
'onClosed' : function() {

}
```

Comment: Thx!! But it doesn't work. Is it because I have "return false; " ?

Comment: ya maybe remove return false and then try.

Comment: Also try my edit , i have used onClosed callback of fancybox.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by declaring `onClosed` option for fancybox initialization.

Take a look at [**API**](http://fancybox.net/api) you will have idea about it.

**Sample Example**

```
$("#various1").fancybox({
  onClosed: function() {
    window.location = "http://index.php";
    return false;
  })
});
```